# Hiding some content on specific layout - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, rendering

I have two layouts - **application.html.erb** and **application.pdf.erb**
They both render the same partial **invoices/show.html.erb**

**invoices/show.html.erb** has a table and a part of it looks like this:

```
<tr>
  <td><%= in.name%></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'remove', some_path(in), method: :delete%></td>
</tr>
```

This is working fine but I would like to remove the link_to when I am rendering **application.pdf.erb** layout. So it looks like this:

```
<tr>
  <td><%= in.name%></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

I have tried to do it by using content_for/yield but I can't have it working.

Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually get the format in your partial:

```
<tr>
  <td><%= in.name%></td>
  <% if controller.request.format == "html" %>
    <td><%= link_to 'remove', some_path(in), method: :delete%></td>
  <% end %>
</tr>
```